# How to Continuously Deploy: VisualStudio.com's tfs Git -> Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, tfs, continuous-deployment

I've got private code in a VisualStudio.com's tfs Git repository.

I'd like to continuously deploy it to Heroku, as code is returned.

What is the simplest/easiest way to do this?

e.g. Does VisualStudio.com support pushing to the Heroku git repository?

Does Heroku support monitoring of any other git repo besides GitHub?

Any other creative solutions? I've got multiple people pushing to the VisualStudio repo, so I'd like to avoid everyone having to configure two push points... if that is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Heroky Release Tools Extension](https://github.com/BoostingMy/vsts-heroku-tasks) in Visual Studio Team Services Marketplace that you could use to deploy to Heroku app. (install [it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=boostingmy.vsts-heroku-tasks) into your VSTS)

1. Create an Heroku App or use an existent one;
2. Retrieve the API Key from an valid App Contributor User;
3. Configure a build definition that generates the final files that should be pushed to Heroku (we recommend you to put all your file structure under a "drop" named folder;
4. Configure a release definition with the Push to Heroku task in it.

Install:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising, but I'm struggling with the documentation. Any idea where I go in VisualStudio.com to have the "Heroku Task" show up? I chose "install" for the tool, but I'm not seeing anything under release definitions in VS.com

Comment: @Doug You need to select a account (e.g. test) when install that extension, then go to that VSTS (https://test.visualstudio.com) and create a new release definition, the Push to Heroku task is in Deploy category.

Comment: Weird, I did the first part but I'm not seeing the task under Deploy. I'll try again, but this is clearly the correct answer.